# Not able to get Transaction Details in Adaptive Payment in paymet

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using parallel adaptive payment. i got the php coding from following link of paypal developer` website.

https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/adaptive/main.php

And i Used IPN listener as follows ,

```
 <?php

// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

    curl_close($ch);
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$from="manikandan.a@quadrantsystems.com";
    $to="manikandan.vkpr@gmail.com";
    $subject="curl_exec".$raw_post_data;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:'.$from."\r\n";
    @mail($to,$subject,print_r($raw_post_array),$headers);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    $from="manikandan.a@quadrantsystems.com";
    $to="manikandan.vkpr@gmail.com";
    $subject="curl_exec".curl_error($ch);
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:'.$from."\r\n";
    @mail($to,$subject,$Message,$headers);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];


     $from="manikandan.a@quadrantsystems.com";
     $to="manikandan.vkpr@gmail.com";
     $subject='success'.$txn_id."paysts".$payment_status."Currency".$payment_currency."Email".$payer_email;
     $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
               $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
               $headers .= 'From:'.$from."\r\n";
               if(@mail($to,$subject,$Message,$headers));

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
     $from="manikandan.a@quadrantsystems.com";
     $to="manikandan.vkpr@gmail.com";
     $subject='invalid'.$item_name;
     $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
               $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
               $headers .= 'From:'.$from."\r\n";
               @mail($to,$subject,$Message,$headers);
    // log for manual investigation

}

?>
```

The first and second mail has executed and mail have been receive, but the the $_POST values are empty.ie

```
 $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
```

After verified following mail function executed but containing empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not seeing the POST values coming back and getting populated into your script correctly because of how they come back, and they are not getting parsed correctly.  When working with Adaptive Payments, the IPN POST's come back in a slightly different format than regular payments.

transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn=...&transaction[0].receiver=paypal_tester_12987336_biz@paypal.com&transaction[0].is_primary_receiver=false&transaction[0].id=...&transaction[0].status=Completed&transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn=Completed&transaction[0].amount=CAD+10.00

You would need to make sure you are parsing the data correctly.

Comment: Passed values are like this only, But after verified, the returned values empty? Or could u please tell me the way to get that transactions details....

Comment: And How can i parse those data?

Comment: You can find some examples at the following URL that may help https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/php-technique-parsing-adaptive-payment-ipn-posts